# Hide all elements except one div and its child element

Tags: jquery, hide

How to hide all elements except one div and its child element using jquery?

Comment: It would depend on where the target `<div>` is located in the HTML markup.

Comment: Perhaps, a little more detailed question would be helpful to answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore that, does not appear to have the desired effect.

<strike>Perhaps the following?</strike>

```
$('body').children().hide();
$('#mydiv').children().andSelf().show();
```

**Update**

The problem is, the visible state of a child DIV often relies on it's parent being visible.  So you need to have an entire tree down to the DIV you want remaining visible.

You need to hide everything apart from that tree, the trick is identifying all children of the DOM structure that are not in the DIV ancestry, and all siblings of the ones that are.

**Finally!**

Managed to write a solution.  Tried a recursive approach at first, but on complicated pages it died with "too much recursion", so wrote a list-based version that works just fine.  It is in the form of a single-function jQuery plugin, as that seems to be the most useful approach.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.allBut = function(context) {
        var target = this;
        var otherList = $();
        var processList = $(context || 'body').children();

        while (processList.size() > 0) {
            var cElem = processList.first();
            processList = processList.slice(1);

            if (cElem.filter(target).size() != target.size()) {
                if (cElem.has(target).size() > 0) {
                    processList = processList.add(cElem.children());
                } else {
                    otherList = otherList.add(cElem);
                }
            }
        }

        return otherList;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This routine finds all elements within the `context` (which defaults to `<body>`) that exclude the object and it's ancestors.

This would achieve the result of the question:

```
$('#mydiv').allBut().hide();
```

Another use could be to retain all objects within a container with a certain class, fading out all the others:

```
$('.keep').allBut('#container').fadeOut();
```

Bare in mind that the layout and positioning of any given element can depend heavily on surrounding elements, so hiding something like that is likely to alter the layout unless things are absolutely positioned.  I can see uses for the routine anyhow.

***However!***

Another poster came up with the following which returns the same information using a routine already built-in to jQuery which I had not seen.

```
target.add(target.parentsUntil(context)).siblings();
```

*or without the variable*

```
target.parentsUntil(context).andSelf().siblings();
```

Which is a tad simpler, must scour documentation in future.

***PS.*** If anyone has a better way of checking if a given jQuery object is equivalent to another than `a.filter(b).size() != b.size()` I would be very glad to hear it!

Comment: It did? Hmm, must be particular to that case.  In general it is not foolproof.

Comment: Likely because `#mydiv` was a direct child of `body`. If that's the case, you could shorten it like this `$('body > :not(#mydiv)').hide();`. I added an answer that works for nested elements.

Comment: @patrick I've added your answer in after mine, so that anyone reading it won't hop off to try it!  Might be nice for people to see code illustrating the methods involved at anyrate.

Answer (score 13):

To target a nested element and make sure it is the only one showing, you would need to hide its siblings, as well as the siblings of all its ancestors until the `<body>`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/gSXYa/1/

```
$('#target').show().parentsUntil('body').andSelf().siblings().hide();
```

---

**EDIT:** *The solution I added above is a little more concise.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/gSXYa/

```
var target = $('#target').show();
target = target.add(target.parentsUntil('body')).siblings().hide();
```

Comment: LOL, your code generates the same output as my almighty block above, did not know about `.parentsUntil()`.

Comment: @Orbling - Sometimes one method makes all the difference in the world. :o) I just simplified mine a little by using `.andSelf()`.

Comment: @user113716 isn't parentsUntil('body') the same as parents() ?

Comment: +1 This needs modified further if you are using multiple selectors but otherwise works great.

Answer (score 4):

This will do `$(".mydivclass").not(this).hide();`

`mydivclass` is the class given to all the divs that needs to be hidden

**Update:**

```
$(".mydivclass").children().hide();
```

will hide all the children element inside `.mydivclass`

Comment: what if `mydivclass` has not mentioned only one `maindiv` with some elements and other div.. then how to hide.

Comment: @Rafee, I am a bit confused... can you explain a bit more

Comment: want to hide all child elements in a `maindiv` and this `maindiv` has some `text` and other input fields and some other divs.

Comment: @Mattis obviously this won't work: if you hide the parent of .mydivclass then .mydivclass will be hidden too...

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: hide all and then show the one(in this case the second div and its children).

```
$('.create-account').children().hide();
$('.create-account>div:nth-of-type(2)').show();
```