# dynamically populate a uiwebview with a certain div class of html?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

depending on what blog post I visit I need a uiwebview to be populated with one div class of html. It's the same div class of html every time, the name doesnt change, just the content.

The div class is called:

```
<div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
```

The content looks like this:

```
    <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>Data centre security is a big issue – especially for co-location centres hosting multiple racks for multiple, often competing, clients. Yet whilst security to access the data centre can often be impressive, individual rack level security is often inadequate. Given the number of in-house staff and external engineers, from cablers to storage and server providers, traipsing through a data centre on a near daily basis, poor rack level security is a potential risk.</p>
<p>According to a recent survey conducted by Lieberman Software, 42 percent of IT staff can get unauthorised access to their organisation’s most sensitive information – including the CEO’s private documents. The failing is blamed on management’s naivety when it comes to understanding just how much privileged access their IT departments actually have.</p>
<p>The fact that most racks are secured only with standard handles using a manual key, bears out this survey. Easily broken or bypassed, these locks provide minimal corporate protection; they offer no access control or audit trail of activity. Given the huge ongoing investment in data centres - during 2011-2012, the UK invested an estimated $3.35 billion in data centres; the second highest spending of any country, according to the Datacentre Dynamics Global Industry Census 2011 - extending standard access control techniques to the data centre racks is an important step.</p>
<p>Companies can opt for a rack specific key, combination locks or key cards that are IP enabled to allow an organisation to impose strict control over the time/day an individual is allowed to access the rack. Using standard access control software, all activity is recorded and audited, providing the organisation with a complete list of those who have accessed the racks.</p>
<p>For organisations, this approach adds control and addresses one important aspect of the internal threat. For co-location sites, rack level security removes the need to cage off client specific rack space areas freeing up space that can be used for more racks, delivering a return on investment, as well as improved client security.</p>
</div>
```

The page can be found [here](http://2bm.co.uk/blog/how-secure-are-your-racks).

I need a method to get the html in that div just from the page url, keep the styling and put it into a string and then populate a uiwebview, can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

better code scenario:

Basically I populate a uitable view from an rss feed of blog posts. This is working fine. Clicking on the blog post returns a url of the blog post clicked on as a string to be used. Its from here where I dont understand how to load this string into a webview, then use jquery on that web view to only display all the content only in that one div class (which is mentioned above.)

Comment: on whichever page u want to populate
make an ajax call which calls the url of the prev page , pick the contents of the div using .children function of jquery then as a response bring it back , then u can populate ur current div
PLZ give specific code scenario for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load everything on the page into the webview, and then run a bit of javascript to hide everything but the div and the contents thereof. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277792/hide-all-elements-except-one-div-and-its-child-element)(well, really, the answer) looks like it would help you accomplish that. If the page is not large, this could be the way to go, as styling would be preserved as a nice side-effect.