# Hide all element except one child div including its children using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a Video player under the div that has myDiv class.
I want to hide the whole web site and just wanted to display the Video i.e myDiv and it's children.How to do it using either jQuery or JavaScript.

```
<body>
   <header></header>
   <main>
      <section></section>
      <section>
        <div class="myDiv">
           <div></div>
           <div</div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section></section>
   </main>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: why not just add a generic `hidden` class?

Comment: You want to hide "everything" or just the content of `main`

Comment: Yes. I want to hide everything except myDiv, There is a Video player in it. I just want to play that Video and hide everything.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277792/hide-all-elements-except-one-div-and-its-child-element

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`filter()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiuiuH6tYPUAhXLuY8KHW3eCzAQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffilter%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIjOndwopfFySn6E1gc8znkMPSPw) function of jquery

```js
$('section').filter(function(){
 return $(this).find('.myDiv').length == 0 //its hiding except myDiv
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <main>
    <section>first</section>
    <section>second contains myDiv
      <div class="myDiv">its a my div
        <div>i m child of myDiv</div>
        <div>i m child of myDiv</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>Third</section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: This is hiding the myDiv, I want to hide everything except that.

Comment: No is not hiding the myDiv .see the snippet @kirangoud

Answer (score 0):

you can give the video div a class and every other div a hide class and write code so that when you click on it to play, it hides everything else.

so in your jquery

```
$('.videoClass').click(function(){
 $('.hide').css('display','none');
});
```

and you can add a toggle so when you click it again, it shows all hidden divs.

Comment: I don't have control over that web site. 